# Как повернуть спрайт не от нижнего левого угла?

Tags: c++, c, математика, спрайт

Переписал на си функцию `glm::rotate`, теперь хочу сделать так, чтобы можно было повернуть изображение относительно другой координаты, а не координаты левого нижнего угла рисунка. Так можно вообще? Я думал что надо что нибудь с cos и sin угол умножить на координаты, но изображение только уменшается и увеличивается.

Comment: И как например сделать чтобы спрайт вращался от центра? Как это в glm библиотеке сделать? А то вращается от своей позиции. Вращается вокруг точки позиции, а не вокруг своего центра изображения.

Comment: У меня матрица поворота * матрицу передвижения высчитываются в шейдере. Это же правильно? Или может быть из-за этого вращается вокруг левого нижнего угла?

Comment: Сначала сместить так, чтобы центр вращения оказался в начале координат, потом вращать, потом перемещать куда нужно.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов похоже с логикой у вас всё в порядке. Но такое невозможно сделать. Или вы знаете как?

Answer (score 0):

Поворот в 2D относительно заданной точки CX, CY можно описать, как отметил Герман Борисов, с помощью последовательности переноса (чтобы центр вращения сместился в начало координат), поворота координат, и обратного переноса. В компактном виде формулы будут такие:

```
X_New = CX + (X - CX) * Cos(Fi) - (Y - CY) * Sin(Fi)
Y_New = CY + (X - CX) * Sin(Fi) + (Y - CY) * Cos(Fi)
```

Comment: Меня не устраивает такой ответ. Хоть может в нём и есть решение, но я не пойму, что такое cx, что такое Fi? И как вы представляете себе перенос центра, вы вообще код видели поворота, это надо делать до того как повернёшь, или в самой функции делать?

Comment: Данная формула является результатом умножения (матрица смещения на (-CX, -CY))*(матрица поворота на угол fi)*(матрица смещения на (CX, CY))

Comment: `вы вообще код видели поворота`- нет, не видел, Вы же его не показали (да как же тебя понять, если ты не говоришь ничего ©` ). Однако данные формулы - результат применения комбинированной матрицы, описанной выше. Что такое cx - я сказал, fi - угол поворота